# Is it possible to use Spring DispatcherServlet to dispatch requests without launch a service?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am using a service like lambda of AWS, which provide an interface named HttpServeletHandler with a method `handle` following:

```kotlin
interface HttpServeletHandler {
    fun handle(reuqest: HttpServletRequest,response: HttpServletResponse)
}
```

What I need to do is to implement `handle` method of the interface, example code following:

```kotlin
class HandlerImpl : HttpServeletHandler {
    fun handle(reuqest: HttpServletRequest,response: HttpServletResponse) {
        // do some customized logic
        response.writer.println("hello world")
    }
}
```

And the service also provides an ip address, so I can send http request to the ip address, and then the method `handle` of `HandlerImpl` will be called automatically.

But the service does not support `spring framework`, so I wonder is there a way to let the service support `spring framework`?

And my idea is following:

```kotlin
class HandlerImpl : HttpServeletHandler {
    fun handle(reuqest: HttpServletRequest,response: HttpServletResponse) {
        // use DispatcherServlet to handle request
        val dispatcherServlet = DispatcherServlet()
        dispatch.service(request, response)
    }
}
```

But finally I got this error:

> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound

I know I did not config `DispatcherServlet` correctly, but I don't know how to config correctly.

So I have 2 questions

1. Is this idea feasible?
2. If the idea is feasible, how to config `DispatcherServlet` correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a wrong idea. The `DispatcherServlet` is your front controller which will detect/select your specific handler to execute, you are doing it the other way around.

Comment: @M.Deinum I see, I just want to use the capabilities of the spring framework to solve this situation. DONOT launch any service, just using `DispatcherServelet` to dispatch the requests from my interface.

Comment: @M.Deinum because the interface do not support spring framework, but I want to use spring. so I cannot launch service, because the interface will send me the request.

Comment: @M.Deinum so I want to config `DispatherSeverlet` correctly so it can detect/select a handler to handle the request from the interface.

Comment: Your question and comments are confusing. An interface doesn't call anything as it is a contract not an implementation. I have no idea what you want to achieve anymore.

Comment: @M.Deinum ok, i will change the question's content.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have rewrite this question, if you can any ideas, please comment, thanks there.

Comment: There is Spring Cloud Function for that.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks, but it's not what I want, I cannot not launch any service by spring, because already have a Faas service like lambda ASW. I just want to use spring to handle reqeust.

Comment: Spring Cloud Function is for Lambda AWS you write a function and it will take care of everything. It doesn't make sense to have your own function start spring boot and do stuff as that would be slow, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: @M.Deinum but the service I use is not Lambda AWS, it is just another service like Lambda AWS.